# I am not able to click on checkbox as there is no tag present for that checkbox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Checkbox is present inside label with link of terms of use

```
<label class="field-item-header" for="fragment-1996782958_acceptAgreement">
I agree to the 
<a target="_blank" href="example.com/terms-of-use">Terms of Use.</a>
</label>
```

previously i was able to click on checkbox but now its clicking on link of terms of use

I have used following xpath to locate checkbox

```
I_AGREE_CHECKBOX = By.xpath("//div[@class='account-information']/fieldset[2]/ul/li[2]/span[1]/label");
```

and

```
I_AGREE_CHECKBOX = By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'I agree to the')]");
```

Please give me some idea so that i can click on checkbox only not on Terms of use
Thanks in advance

Comment: under label there is only a tag. Are you sure you are providing correct html snippet here. Please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following expression:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'I agree to the'))]]
```

Comment: I have used xpath given by you //*[text()[contains(.,'I agree to the')]] still it clicks on link Terms of Use link

Comment: I cant share it its confidential

Comment: to have access to the content of the for attribute which I suppose is used to activate the checkbox, use //*[text()[contains(.,'I agree to the')]]/@for

Comment: By using `//*[text()[contains(.,'I agree to the')]]/@for` TimeoutException thrown

Comment: without access to the code I built a simulation environment here: http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester and the expression is correct. Any more info about your settings ? The issue could be related to Selenium. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947290/query-related-to-explicit-wait-wait-untilexpectedconditions-visibilityofelemen and http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10144/timeoutexception-when-trying-to-identify-dropdown-element-in-last-iteration-of-f